# Passing a variable as part of an argument of a command

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to pass a variable as part of an argument to a command. Specifically, I want `mysqldump` to return elements whose ID is above some number. For example, this line works and returns all elements with ID above 30: `mysqldump --user=MYUSER -p -B DB --tables sometable --where='id>30'`.

I have a script that determines this number and assigns it to variable LASTID. I would like to pass the value of this variable into the argument (in place of "30"). I  run this:

`mysqldump --user=MYUSER -p -B DB --tables sometable --where='id>"${LASTID}"'`

But it returns the entire database, instead of using the correct id. It is as if it is ignoring what I am passing to LASTID.

I also tried this:

`eval $(mysqldump --user=MYUSER -p -B DB --tables sometable --where='id>"${LASTID}"')` and `eval echo $(mysqldump --user=MYUSER -p -B DB --tables sometable --where='id>"${LASTID}"')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's:

```
mysqldump --user=MYUSER -p -B DB --tables sometable --where="id>${LASTID}"
```

Research the difference between single and double quotes in shell. Check your scripts with shellcheck. Eval is one letter from evil - do not use eval.

Comment: Last sentence made my day

Comment: Of course! Silly me. I did learn the difference, but I added them around the variable instead of the whole argument. Thanks so much!

Comment: And wow I found the script spellcheck. It looks invaluable. Although I suspect you are gonna complain about invaluable being too close to evaluable or containing all the letters of evil.